# Error in processing IP address in command line argument

Tags: c

```
/****************** CLIENT CODE ****************/ socket connection

int main( int argc,char *argv[] )// main function
{
        int opt,port,i=0,j=1,addr_size;
        int clientSocket;
        char buffer[MAX];
        char server_ip[9];
        struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

        while ((opt = getopt (argc, argv, "p:i:")) != -1)
        {
                switch (opt)
                {
                case 'p':
                        port=atoi(optarg);
                        break;
                case 'i':
                        i=atoi(optarg);
                        break;
```

//commenting strcpy and hardcoding the ip address works without any problem. if try to strcpy it from the command line it connects with the server and hangs the the while loop below

```
                //case 'a':
                //      strcpy(server_ip,optarg);
                //      break;
                deault:
                        printf ("No arguments\n");
                        exit(0);
                }
        }

        clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
        serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.2.15");
        addr_size = sizeof (serverAddr);

        connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, addr_size);

        j=1;

        while(j<=i)
        {

                send(clientSocket,"Client1",MAX,0);

                if(recv(clientSocket, buffer, 1024, 0)>0)
                        printf("Data received: %s\n",buffer);
                j++;
                sleep(1);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that your use of the label `deault:` inside a `switch` is valid but unorthodox — and it isn't the same as the `default:` case label would be.  There really isn't a question visible here.  I think the comment I left as plain text is where you're trying to ask something, but you should really be clearer about what you're asking.  The opening comment is followed by invalid C, too (`/* … */ socket connection`).

Answer (score 0):

```
char server_ip[9];
```

is not big enough, IP4 address will be max 15 characters long and one char for `\0` so you should declare your variable as

```
char server_ip[16];
```

Even if you enter 10.0.2.15, you are one char short as it wll need 10 characters to store this ip considering null character.

You are likely to hit another undefined behaviour here:

```
        send(clientSocket,"Client1",MAX,0);
```

if MAX is greater than 7 (length of "Client1"), as `send()` will try to read beyond bounds of string literal "Client1". 
You should pass proper send buffer and its size to send() function, you should correct these situations leading to undefined behaviors and try again

Comment: Thank you for your valuable inputs and its working now

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

1. your char array `server_ip[9]` is of insufficient length. It should be at least 16 byte long - `server_ip[16]`.
2. you don't have an option to parse 'a' in `getopt`. `getopt (argc, argv, "p:i:")` should be `getopt (argc, argv, "p:i:a:")`